# Interval of convergence of power series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

If the power series is:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{\sqrt{n+1}}
$$

and I've found the interval to be $$ -1 < x < 1 $$ then would the answer $$ (-1, 1) $$ work? some other options are $$ (-1, 1] $$ and $$ [-1, 1] $$ ?

Answer (score 0):

By ratio test you can find that the series converges if $\left|x\right|<1
 $. In this case this series admits a closed form in terms of special functions. In fact we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{x^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=x\sum_{n\geq0}\frac{x^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=x\Phi\left(x,\frac{1}{2},x\right)
 $$ where $\Phi\left(x,s,a\right)
 $ is the [Lerch Trascendent](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LerchTranscendent.html). For $x=1
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{1}{n+1}=\infty
 $$ and for $x=-1
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}=\sum_{n\geq1}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n-1}}{\sqrt{n}}-1=\eta\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-1
 $$ where $\eta\left(s\right)
 $ is the [Dirichlet eta function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DirichletEtaFunction.html).

Comment: The Lerch function is at best a diversion if one wants to prove that the interval of convergence is $$\color{red}{\mathbf [-1,1)}.$$